# FtpWebRequest uploads files with zero

Tags: c#, xamarin

Im using FtpWebRequest to upload files through:

```
ftp.Upload(filename,filepath);
```

Being my ftp class:

```
class ftp
{
private string host = null;
private string user = null;
private string pass = null;
private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
private Stream ftpStream = null;
private int bufferSize = 2048;

public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {

        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
}
```

And files do Upload, but all filles upload with size 0.

What can I do to make my files upload as they should?
I already tried setting Binary and Passive as false and there was no difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're actually wanting to do: FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);

At the moment you are creating a empty file and trying to read 2048 bytes from that empty file.

Comment: If I use using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "xxxxx");
                        client.UploadFile("ftp://xxxxxx/public_html/cloud/" + foldercreate + "/" + filename, "STOR", pathacrear);
                    }

I get the same thing. 0 sized files